# Sylpheed not auto checking IMAP accounts

Tags: email, imap

I just installed Sylpheed 3.5.1 from the Debian repository.  I configured my 3 IMAP accounts (2 GMail and a Yahoo Mail), and they all work properly, sending and receiving mail as they should be.

I have it set to auto-check for new mail every 5 minutes, but it never seems to check any accounts for new messages.  It doesn't check for new messages until I open the mail window and press `Get`.  `Get All`, which seems like it should get the new mail for all accounts, does not do anything, and `Get` gets mail for all accounts.

I tested this by sending an email from one account to the other and waiting for Sylpheed to report a new message.  The whole time Sylpheed was kept minimized in the dock and in online mode.  After a half hour, Sylpheed did not report any new messages, and the protocol log was blank.  It wasn't until I pressed `Get` that the messages where retrieved.

I have been searching around, and there doesn't seem to be anyone else describing this problem.  In fact, there doesn't seem to be many people talking about Sylpheed in general (at least relative to other email clients).  The manual and online documentation were also pretty sparse, and barely even mention the auto check feature.  I am specifying that the mailboxes are accessed with IMAP because in general, there seem to be more people with problems with IMAP mailboxes, even though the protocol really shouldn't make a difference in this case.  I don't want to configure Sylpheed to use POP3 and risk losing emails to test it.

My question is does anyone know how to get Sylpheed to automatically check IMAP accounts?